# Log in to Azure in a script without entering a password explicitly

Tags: azure, authentication

I have a script that pushes a Docker Container to an Azure Container Registry. But before that, one needs to log in to Azure, which requires a password (either it's a user, or a service principal). That is not an option, since this password will be explicit and visible in code.

Any chance to log in another way, without explicit credentials?

Answer (score 0):

The only possible ways for Azure CLI are User or Service Principal. You could do the authentication outside of the script if it helps. Or if it helps, Service Principals could also use a certificate to authenticate. If you don't commit it (.gitignore) it should stay on your machine only.

If you are in a build pipeline in Azure DevOps or GitHub, there are ways to handle connections and secrets without exposing them to the code.

Comment: Maybe I could actually use a certificate, and restrict read access to the file, so that only an authorized user could see the actual contents of the certificate. Thanks